# How do you check if a child node is empty with a query in azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am currently working Azure Cosmos DB. I would know how to query if a child node is empty. I im looking for the query to return all documents where the rootobject is empty.

{
"id": "5d3e7ff1-94ea-4471-afaf-3c7b76e0b943",
"informationDate": "2020-09-07",
"rootobject": { }
}

Comment: You can have a check as `rootobject = null` assuming it will be `null` when empty. Can you confirm what is the value you are setting for an empty value of `rootobject`

Answer (score 2):

You can construct array then check this array whether only contains `{}`：

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS([c.rootobject],{}) and ARRAY_LENGTH([c.rootobject]) = 1
```

don't check array length can also work fine:

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS([c.rootobject],{})
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query will return documents that have an empty rootobject:

SELECT * FROM c where c.rootobject = {}